# I need to modify a .bat script in a described way

Tags: batch-file

So I have this script that takes files (.txtS for example), makes a folder of the same name for each one and moves 'em inside, each to the corresponding folder.

```bash
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

What I'd like to change is for the script to do the same thing but with Folders. So, take folder "1", create another folder "1" and move the first one inside. Willing to compromise on the name a little due to expected "this folder name is already taken" behavior.

I tried looking through Microsoft's documentation, but there are almost no matches for a newb like me to get an understanding of what's going on in the script (it was taken from another resource)

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. Pay close attention to the `/D` option. Alternatively you may wish to consider the `/F` option alongside the `DIR` command. `[ENTER]` `dir /?` in a Command Prompt window, paying particular attention to the `/A:` option, with the `D` parameter.

Comment: I'm sure it makes sense, but I simply can't comprehend it. I couldn't make sense of half of what's written in the script (like I said, documentation wasn't of much help to me). I've no idea where I would put "/d" (after "for", I know, but to which of those I don't know) and what it would to /exactly/.. Thanks for your help anyway, but I guess I'll just go ahead and make all of described happen manually. A few hundred times, that is...

Comment: Good luck with your decision.